# Resolved - Uploading Product Images From Custom Module Admin Form

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, grid, product-images

I have a custom grid. Need to upload product images from admin form of the custom module.

Here is the grid Edit file at

> app\code\local\Cpstest\ProductComment\Block\Adminhtml\Cps\Edit\Form.php

```
<?php
class Cpstest_ProductComment_Block_Adminhtml_Cps_Edit_Form extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->setId('cpstest_productcomment_cps_form');
        $this->setTitle($this->__('Product Comments Information'));
    }

    protected function _prepareForm()
    {
        $model = Mage::registry('cpstest_productcomment');

        $form = new Varien_Data_Form(array(
            'id'        => 'edit_form',
            'action'    => $this->getUrl('*/*/save', array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id'))),
            'method'    => 'post'
        ));

        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('base_fieldset', array(
            'legend'    => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Product Comments Information'),
            'class'     => 'fieldset-wide',
        ));

        if ($model->getId()) {
            $fieldset->addField('id', 'hidden', array(
                'name' => 'id',
            ));
        }

        $fieldset->addField('name', 'text', array(
            'name'      => 'name',
            'label'     => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Customer Name'),
            'title'     => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Customer Name'),
            'required'  => true,
            'class'     =>'input-text required-entry validate-no-html-tags',
        ));

        ...

        $form->setValues($model->getData());
        $form->setUseContainer(true);
        $this->setForm($form);
        return parent::_prepareForm();
    }
}
```

> Here is the controller SaveAction:

```
public function saveAction()
{
    if ($postData = $this->getRequest()->getPost()) {
        $model = Mage::getSingleton('cpstest_productcomment/cps');
        $model->setData($postData);

        try {
            $model->save();
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess($this->__('The comment has been saved.'));
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
            return;
        } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($this->__('An error occurred while saving this comment.'));
        }
        Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setCpsData($postData);
        $this->_redirectReferer();
    }
}
```

Comment: do you just want to display  image or you want to update image ?

Comment: Hi @MurtuzaZabuawala , I would like to upload new product images from the grid edit page. I was able to add the 'browse' button, but the images are not being uploaded and saved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add image field by below code.

```
$fieldset->addField('image', 'image', array(
    'label'     => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Image'),
    'required'  => false, // Make true if required field
    'name'      => 'image',
));
```

Add below code to your `saveAction`

```
public function saveAction()
{
    if ($postData = $this->getRequest()->getPost()) {
        try {
            if ((bool)$post_data['image']['delete']==1) {
                $post_data['image']='';
            } else {
                unset($post_data['image']);
                if (isset($_FILES)) {
                    if ($_FILES['image']['name']) {
                        if ($this->getRequest()->getParam("id")) {
                            $model = Mage::getSingleton('cpstest_productcomment/cps')->load($this->getRequest()->getParam("id"));
                            if ($model->getData('image')) {
                                $io = new Varien_Io_File();
                                $io->rm(Mage::getBaseDir('media').DS.implode(DS,explode('/',$model->getData('image'))));    
                            }
                        }

                        $path = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'Cpstest' . DS .'ProductComment'.DS;
                        $uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader('image');
                        $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('jpg','png','gif'));
                        $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(false);
                        $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);
                        $destFile = $path.$_FILES['image']['name'];
                        $filename = $uploader->getNewFileName($destFile);
                        $uploader->save($path, $filename);

                        $post_data['image']='Cpstest/ProductComment/'.$filename;
                        $mediaAttribute = array (
                            'image',
                            'thumbnail',
                            'small_image'                  
                        );
                        $_product = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->load();
                        $_product->addImageToMediaGallery($path.$filename, $mediaAttribute, true, false);
                        $_product->save();
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
            $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id')));
            return;
        }

        $model = Mage::getSingleton('cpstest_productcomment/cps');
        $model->setData($postData);

        try {
            $model->save();
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess($this->__('The comment has been saved.'));
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
            return;
        } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($this->__('An error occurred while saving this comment.'));
        }
        Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setCpsData($postData);
        $this->_redirectReferer();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Jaimin, thanks for help. I tried this solution and added the print screen to my question. It displays a button to upload an image, but looks like it doesn't work, the image is not being uploaded.

Comment: Can you share your controller saveAction code?

Comment: Hi @Jaimin, I have added it to my question.

Comment: @bestwebdevs, for saving image, you can use saveAction from Sathish's answer. Also please add your grid image renderer code to the question to check on which path you are saving your images.

Comment: Here you are using product image. Do you want to upload your images to products?

Comment: Yes  @Jaimin , I want to upload them to products.

Comment: @bestwebdevs, Please check updated code for image upload.

Comment: Hi @Jaimin, thanks for your response. Your solution is uploading images correctly, but still the thumbnails don't show up on the admin form. But I decided to post a different question for that issue and will mark your answer as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

> You need to alter your controller to save image or delete images (unset images) like below.

```
public function saveAction()
{
    if ($postData = $this->getRequest()->getPost()) {
        try {
            if ((bool)$post_data['image']['delete']==1) {
                $post_data['image']='';
            } else {
                unset($post_data['image']);
                if (isset($_FILES)) {
                    if ($_FILES['image']['name']) {
                        if ($this->getRequest()->getParam("id")) {
                            $model = Mage::getSingleton('cpstest_productcomment/cps')->load($this->getRequest()->getParam("id"));
                            if ($model->getData('image')) {
                                $io = new Varien_Io_File();
                                $io->rm(Mage::getBaseDir('media').DS.implode(DS,explode('/',$model->getData('image'))));    
                            }
                        }

                        $path = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'Cpstest' . DS .'ProductComment'.DS;
                        $uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader('image');
                        $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('jpg','png','gif'));
                        $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(false);
                        $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);
                        $destFile = $path.$_FILES['image']['name'];
                        $filename = $uploader->getNewFileName($destFile);
                        $uploader->save($path, $filename);

                        $post_data['image']='Cpstest/ProductComment/'.$filename;
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
            $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id')));
            return;
        }

        $model = Mage::getSingleton('cpstest_productcomment/cps');
        $model->setData($postData);

        try {
            $model->save();
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess($this->__('The comment has been saved.'));
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
            return;
        } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($this->__('An error occurred while saving this comment.'));
        }
        Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setCpsData($postData);
        $this->_redirectReferer();
    }
}
```

for adding image in edit view, as per jaimin sutariya said. you can add image field set

```
$fieldset->addField('image', 'image', array(
    'label' => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Image'),
    'name' => 'image',
    'required'  => false, // Make true if required field
    'note' => '(*.jpg, *.png, *.gif)',
));
```

Comment: Hi @Sathish, I tried but the image was not uploaded.

Comment: how you checked? on folder or db? try to debug using var_dump($_FILES); posted or not?

Comment: I checked the database table catalog_product_entity_media_gallery and also the folder.

Comment: can you share more detail like model, config and schema details?

Comment: I have added more details @Satish. And as an additional info - here is how the grid works: when you press on any row of the grid (besides 'product front url' and 'product back-end url') it redirects to grid edit page.